# Change the data source Of Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I need to change the data source of an `Adapter` according to the value obtained from a `Spinner`. It works correctly when the activity starts and the default value of the spinner is 0, but when I change the value of the spinner it does not work. How could this be done?

Here is my `EventListener`:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            mViewPager.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = null;
            mViewPager.removeAllViews();

            switch (position){
                case 0 : ListOfFood = bef;break;
                case 1 : ListOfFood= chek;break;
            }
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabbed.this, ListOfFood);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to use `mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` instead `position` in switch statement.

Comment: it is not the problem , the spinner works correctly and the value of ListofFood changes correctly after changing the value of the spinner ,the problem is that the view on my lis view does not changed !

Comment: You have to notify the adapter as well for the change in dataset...
try calling notifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter

Comment: or invalidate() your ListView

Comment: use `mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` to notify changes.

Comment: mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged() and myViewPager.invalidate() do not work. 
note* myViewPager is an ViewPager Layout component not a Listview .

Comment: Okay, so your app has two `Fragments`, agree?. What type of views contains your `Fragments`?

Comment: ImageView , textView and check Buttons